# CSS - How to remove comments and make CSS one line

Tags: css

I would like to know how to remove all comments in CSS file and make all rules into one line.

I do have access to Dreamweaver CS4.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is a good cross-platform css compressor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183434/what-is-a-good-cross-platform-css-compressor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one: [CSS Compressor](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor)

Answer (score 2):

if you can run PHP, you can do it one of these ways. benefit of keeping the code readable for yourself and only on rendering it is minified.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php

you also have the YUI compressor: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

also look up the [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) project. It combines multiple CSS and JS files and minifies them as well.

Comment: The first link you gave me is not related to this question.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

[YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) does CSS as well as JS.

Answer (score 1):

Google gave me this: [CSSCompressor](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor).

See also [“CSS Minimzer ?” on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633508/css-minimizer).